# How do I separate the City, State, and Zip code from a string

Tags: python, zip, state, city

I have a database of addresses and I want to separate them into individual strings:

Input:

#Address #1

> 194 RIVERSIDE DRIVE

#City, State, Zip

> OYSTER BAY NY 11018

Output:

#Address #1

194 RIVERSIDE DRIVE

#City

OYSTER BAY

#State

NY

#Zip

11018

The Address #1, I could get easily because it is in a separate line but how would I go about separating the City, State, and Zip since they are on the same line and in the same string?
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Maybe work backwards, start by stripping the zip from the end (one continuous block), then the state (two letters if abbreviated), then the city. If this doesn't work, give some more examples to help us help you